# What is wrong with this code to convert all elements of a list to a LaTeX file?

Tags: list-manipulation, latex

I have a list that I need to convert to LaTeX:

```
lis={{(x^2+12 x+19) (x^2+12 x+12)-8==0,x==-11||x==-10||x==-2||x==-1},{(x^2+13 x+20) (x^2+13 x+14)-16==0,x==-12||x==-11||x==-2||x==-1}};
```

I am trying convert all elements of the list to
[image]

I tried

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
fileName=FileNameJoin[{Directory[],"thu_may.tex"}]
If[FileExistsQ[fileName],DeleteFile[fileName]];
file=OpenWrite[fileName,PageWidth->Infinity];
WriteString[file,"\\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}\n"<>"\\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2 cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}\n"<>"\\usepackage{enumitem}\n"<>"\\begin{document}\n"<>"\\begin{enumerate}[label=\\arabic*)]\n"];

format[e_List]:=("$"<>ToString[e[[1]]]<>"$ \\hfill Answer. $"<>ToString[e[[2]]]<>"$.");
Do[myTMP=format[lis[[n]]];
myTMP=StringReplace[myTMP,"||"->"\\lor"];
myTMP=StringReplace[myTMP,"=="->"="];
WriteString[file,"\\item "<>myTMP<>"\n"],{n,1,Length@lis}];
WriteString[file,"\\end{enumerate}\n\\end{document}\n"];
Close[file]
```

Text file

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2 cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
\item $  2                2
(x  + 12 x + 19) (x  + 12 x + 12) - 8 = 0$ \hfill Answer. $x = -11 \lor x = -10 \lor x = -2 \lor x = -1$.
\item $  2                2
(x  + 13 x + 20) (x  + 13 x + 14) - 16 = 0$ \hfill Answer. $x = -12 \lor x = -11 \lor x = -2 \lor x = -1$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I get the correct result?

Comment: The alignment you are asking for is not easy to do using what you have. You have to use different Latex. But Is this OK?  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfhiB.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem you had is that you used

```
ToString[expr]
```

Where `expr` was math.  This is a no-no. When you have

```
expr = x^2
```

And you do `ToString[expr]` you get embbeded new lines added.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

That is a carriage return there represented by `\n` ofcourse you do not want this.  If you do not want the Latex, but still want plain string, you have to wrap the expression first by `InputForm` before calling ToString.

This result in 1D string (no new line)

```
expr = x^2;
ToString[InputForm@expr]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The same for Mathematica 2D math

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want the Latex, then you just call `TeXForm` but have to convert it to string. Since you called `TeXForm` now it comes out 1D and you do not have to worry about Mathematica adding `\n` in the middle

```
expr = x^2;
ToString[TeXForm@expr]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Given all of this, now your code works:

```
lis = {{(x^2 + 12  x + 19)  (x^2 + 12  x + 12) - 8 == 0, 
   x == -11 || x == -10 || x == -2 || 
    x == -1}, {(x^2 + 13  x + 20)  (x^2 + 13  x + 14) - 16 == 0, 
   x == -12 || x == -11 || x == -2 || x == -1}}
```

Then

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
fileName = FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "thu_may.tex"}]
If[FileExistsQ[fileName], DeleteFile[fileName]];
file = OpenWrite[fileName, PageWidth -> Infinity];
WriteString[file, 
  "\\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}\n" <> 
   "\\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2 cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}\n" \
<> "\\usepackage{enumitem}\n" <> "\\begin{document}\n" <> 
   "\\begin{enumerate}[label=\\arabic*)]\n"];

format[e_List] := ("$" <> ToString[TeXForm[e[[1]]]] <> 
    "$\\newline Answer. $" <> ToString[TeXForm[e[[2]]]] <> "$.");
Do[myTMP = format[lis[[n]]];
  myTMP = StringReplace[myTMP, "||" -> "\\lor"];
  myTMP = StringReplace[myTMP, "==" -> "="];
  WriteString[file, "\\item " <> myTMP <> "\n"], {n, 1, Length@lis}];
WriteString[file, "\\end{enumerate}\n\\end{document}\n"];
Close[file]
```

Gives

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2 cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
\item $\left(x^2+12 x+12\right) \left(x^2+12 x+19\right)-8=0$\newline Answer. $x=-11\lor x=-10\lor x=-2\lor x=-1$.
\item $\left(x^2+13 x+14\right) \left(x^2+13 x+20\right)-16=0$\newline Answer. $x=-12\lor x=-11\lor x=-2\lor x=-1$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

And the PDF is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want the **Answer** portion be shifted to the far right, new formatting Latex have to be written. But I think the above is clear as is. **Answer** portion starts on new line using `\\newline`

If you are using Mathematica to convert your notebook content to Latex, you almost always will be using

```
ToString[TeXForm[expr]]
```

And never

```
ToString[expr]
```

As there is really little reason to the use the second one above. I use `ToString[TeXForm[expr]]` so much, I have small function made so I do not have to keep typing it

```
toX[e_]:=ToString[TeXForm[e]]
```

And now you can just to  `toX[expr]` for everything. Less typing.  Now your `format` function becomes

```
format[e_List] := ("$" <> toX[e[[1]]] <> "$\\newline Answer. $" <> 
    toX[e[[2]]] <> "$.");
```