# How can I convert a text file to mathematica to past to WriteString?

Tags: latex

I have a text file like this

```
  \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[left=2cm,right=2 cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{ninecolors}
    \usepackage{fouriernc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,
        booktabs,
        counter,
        diagbox,
        siunitx,
        varwidth}
     \newcounter{mycnta}
     \newcommand{\mycnta}{\stepcounter{mycnta}\arabic{mycnta}} 
     \begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[
        caption={The function $y = \dfrac{a x^2 + b x + c}{m  x + n}$ }]{
            colspec = {cllcc},
            cells={mode=dmath},
            row{1}={mode=text,c,yellow9},
            rowhead = 1, 
            hline{1,2,Z} = {solid}
        }
        Order & Function $y = f(x)$ &  $y'= f'(x)$ & Point $A$ & Point $B$

\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

I would like to convert the text file in the form

```
"\\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}\n" <> 
   "\\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2 cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}\n" \
<> "\\usepackage{enumitem}\n" <> "\\usepackage{ninecolors}\n" <> 
   "\\usepackage{fouriernc}\n" <> 
   "\\usepackage{amsmath}\n" <> "\\usepackage{tabularray}\n" <> 
   "\\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,
\tbooktabs,
\tcounter,
\tdiagbox,
\tsiunitx,
\tvarwidth}\n" <> 
   " \\newcounter{mycnta}\n \
\\newcommand{\\mycnta}{\\stepcounter{mycnta}\\arabic{mycnta}} \n \
\\begin{document}\n" <> "\\begin{longtblr}[
\tcaption={The function $y = \\dfrac{a x^2 + b x + c}{m  x + n}$ }]{
\t\tcolspec = {cllcc},
\t\tcells={mode=dmath},
\t\trow{1}={mode=text,c,yellow9},
\t\trowhead = 1, 
\t\thline{1,2,Z} = {solid}
\t}
\tOrder & Function $y = f(x)$ &  $y'= f'(x)$ & Point $A$ & Point $B$\n\
"];
"\\end{longtblr}\n\\end{document}\n"
```

I do this by hand. How to tell *Mathematica* convert?

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) for me. If you could please explain more why you want to do this, there could be a much easier way to do what you really trying to do. I've been using Latex with Mathematica for many many years and never had once to read a Latex file into Mathematica and convert it to string. If you want to read a latex code fragment into Latex, just use `\import` or `\input` commands.  What use case/workflow do you have where you need to do what you are asking for?

Comment: I see [your answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/297137/what-is-wrong-with-this-code-to-convert-all-elements-of-a-list-to-a-latex-file). E.g, you input `WriteString[file, 
  "\\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}\n" <> 
   "\\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2 cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}\n" \
<> "\\usepackage{enumitem}\n" <> "\\begin{document}\n" <> 
   "\\begin{enumerate}[label=\\arabic*)]\n"];` What is way you input code?

Comment: In that answer I typed the latex code directly into Mathematica notebook. I did not read it from external file. If you plan to do this alot, then I recommend putting this commenly used  Latex code into a small external .tex file and in Mathematica just add `\input{external_file}` to your latex that you are generating from Mathematica. If this is not clear I can show you an example.

Comment: Use Mathematica to only generated the Latex for the computation you are doing. For any common static code that does not change (such as preamble) you read it from external files/

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try later.

Comment: Can you give me an example about your work?

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested? All what you have to do is add "\\input{my_file}"  to your Mathematica string which will be written to the final Latex file you are writing to.  Inside `my_file.tex` will be the preamble code (i.e. all the Latex code you want to load) which does not need to be generated by Mathematica.  The file `my_file.tex` is separate file which you create yourself.